# SSRS 2012 not rendering charts in a PDF (A generic error occurred in GDI+)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I have a data driven subscription that renders the report in PDF. SSRS 2012, Win 2008 R2 (on Hyper-V) is used.

I have looked in `ExecutionLog3`, the shared data sets all successfully refresh, the reports successfully render and are output to the correct folder.

I did read somewhere that when rendering the reports in IE that the user needed permissions to the `Temporary Internet Files` folder, however I don't know if this is valid for data driven subscriptions? I did add the execution account (a local user) to have read/write permissions on the ReportServer temp internet folder.

Apart from this I have no idea what to look for to troubleshoot this issue? Any suggestions will be welcomed.

**EDIT - 2012-11-19**

Have found the following unhandled exception error in the ReportServer log:

```cs
ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingObjectModelException: A generic error occurred in GDI+. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.Chart.WebForms.Chart.Save(Stream imageStream, ChartImageFormat format)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ChartMapper.GetImage(ImageType imageType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
```

Comment: Pruebe con una nueva versión de reportviewer:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the GDI+ drivers needed updating on Windows 2008 R2 Server and is a known issue. If you want to know what version of GDI+ you have then do a file search for `gdiplus.dll`.

I posted the same question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/50c071db-b4fc-4a2e-a9f4-e10e833c97d2) and got a response saying to update the drivers via a hotfix, which can be found [at this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2495074?wa=wsignin1.0), and it provides the version of the `gdiplus.dll` that will be installed with the hotfix, so you can compare if there is a version change necessary.

You need to request the hotfix, and an email will be sent to you giving you the download location.

`This also solved the issue of images not rendering as well as charts`