# How to handling "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

Tags: reporting-services, gdi+, windows-server-2008-r2, export-to-pdf, hresult

I Use Reporting Services for my software ,  when i Export the Report as PDF (or TIFF) , this error occurs: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"
http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-11/81277343609975485437.png

I am sure of the accuracy of the report design  and it work on another Server Correctly. also in the Graphical Reports and Charts I see " a Generic Error Occurred in GDI+ " instead the chart!

http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-11/81277343609975485437.png

I Searched the Problem in several Forums,someone Recommended to Updating Windows,reinstalling Driver of Graphical Hardware and Someone advice to installing KB2495074 and like it,..  I try ,but i can't handle this Error .
i See this Error on Windows Server 2008R2 , Windows Server 2012  and MS SQL Server 2008R2 , MS SQL Server 2012 . 
Finally I try to Using StimulReport as alternative of reporting service, But when i Export the Report as PDF  , this error occurs: "PdfFonts error at point 5, code #80004005: The operation completed successfully"
the Export of PDF of Report work in another machine Correctly!

Same Address/95563046108540215667.png

This Error Occurred on various Server and I can't Handle It.
Please Help Me, I am waiting for your suggestions.

Comment: you've cut off most of the stacktrace text in your screenshot.

Comment: Dear  @Mike D you can see full stack trace at this link http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=73008180848989966079

Comment: @MikeD. please give me your comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS 2012 not rendering charts in a PDF (A generic error occurred in GDI+)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329739/ssrs-2012-not-rendering-charts-in-a-pdf-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi)

Comment: My Windows and MS SQL Server was Updated and Every Updates Are Installed.